# How to handle different sequence sizes during training and production use?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

My training data consists of sequences that are mode of tokens.

The objective of my model is to predict score for each token in the input sequence. This score depends on the particular token itself, its position in the sequence and actual whole sequence as well.

One way how to approach this is to have model whose input/output dimensions are same $(n, n)$. However, this does not work for me because length of the sequences in my training dataset differ from the ones that will be used in production (production ones will be 2x longer). We can only work with this constrained data for now.

I'm aware that I can change the model to predict one score for each input token and its feature vector whose size does not change with sequence length (e.g. I'll be using only "local" features), but I would like the underlying model to learn the features by itself just by providing the whole sequence and output score for each sequence's token.

What are some possible NN architectures that can handle this problem?

Comment: Why not just use a transformer model to process variable length sequences and predict the score at each token? Add upper triangular masking if future tokens leak information about past tokens

Comment: Would not my model completely break during production, if it did not see any of the longer sequence during training?

Comment: It probably would, but that's a data problem - you can't fix that on the model level. Maybe you can break long inference sequences into "train sequence size" chunks but I can't say if that's a good idea or not without knowing more about the sequences themselves. You should focus on developing a training dataset that is representative of your production inference use case.

Comment: I completely agree with @Karl about the utter importance of having training data that is representative of the final data the model is going to receive. If the score of a token depends on its absolute position in the sequence, it would be difficult to make prediction for longer sequences than those seen during training. I would try to test some hypotheses to see if you can make assumptions to relax this. For instance, you may assume that the score does not actually depend on the absolute position of the token in the sequence but instead depends on a window of tokens around it.